# SharePoint List to Access

Tags: access

I have a SharePoint Lists linked to an Access Database. Can you keep the information that was deleted in the SharePoint List in the Access database?

Answer (score 2):

A SharePoint list can be "saved" in Access a few ways:

1. When connecting to the SharePoint list, you are asked if you want to "link" the list or "import" the list. If you import the list it will be just as if you imported an excel document or a text file. A copy of the data is stored locally. Changes to the local data are not reflected in the source, changes in the source are not reflected in the local data.
2. Use the "convert to local table" available from the right-click context menu of a linked sharepoint list. This changes a "linked" list to an "imported" list per #1.
3. Use the non-2010+ caching mechanism which enables you to "work offline". To do this, go to `File -> Options -> Current Database -> Caching Web Service and SharePoint Tables` and uncheck `Use the cache format that is compatible with Microsoft Access 2010 and Later`. Once you do this, you will see a new option on the External Data ribbon tab that allows you to work offline and manually choose when to synch your cached data.

https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Work-offline-with-tables-that-are-linked-to-SharePoint-lists-5d66594a-6176-4a25-a198-320f13ccf41e

You can always export the current contents of a list, query or table to a file at any time if you plan on deleting data but want to keep a copy.